# Creating a data1 versus data2 plot?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, data

I have a table of data with multiple rows and columns, and I have to make a versus data table using two of these columns.  Essentially, I have to set one column of data (column 3) as the y-axis and another column of data (column 5) as the x-axis.  How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming the name of the table is `data`

```
data =
  {
   {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6},
   {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7},
   {3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8},
   {4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
   };
```

The 3rd column would be data[[All,3]] and the 5th data[[All,3]]. `All` means: take all elements of the given index. Since we need to plot x against y we need a submatrix containing the 3rd and 5th column. Data[[All,{5,3}]] does that.

```
data[[All, {5, 3}]]

(*
==> {{5, 3}, {6, 4}, {7, 5}, {8, 6}}
*)
```

There are many plot functions in Mathematica. In this case, `ListPlot` or `ListLinePlot` are appropriate.

```
ListPlot[data[[All,{5,3}]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ListLinePlot[data[[All,{5,3}]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

There are many, many options to tune those plots. I suggest looking up those in the extensive electronic documentation in the Help menu or by selecting a command and pressing F1 (Windows)

Things to look up:

- [Part](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Part.html) ( [[...]] )
- [Manipulating Elements Of Lists](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ManipulatingElementsOfLists.html)
- [Getting Pieces Of Lists](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/GettingPiecesOfLists.html)
- The [data visualization overview page](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/DataVisualization.html) and its descendants
- The [function visualization overview page](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/FunctionVisualization.html) and its descendants

Answer (score 11):

You could do something like

```
ListLinePlot[data[[All, {5, 3}]]]
```

Answer (score 11):

### Short version

Use [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Part.html).

### Longer version

Let's create a dataset consisting of $x$, $x^2$, $\sin(x)$ and $\exp(x)$.

```
data = Table[{x, x^2, Sin[x], Exp[x]}, {x, 0, 10, .1}]
```

> ```
> {{0., 0., 0., 1.}, <<99>>, {10., 100., -0.544021, 22026.5}}
> ```

Now let's plot $\exp(x)$ over $x^2$.

**The intuitive way** of doing this is extracting two separate lists from the dataset, namely the second and fourth columns, by using `data[[All, 2]]` (or `4`, respectively), combining them into a new list, which then consists of `{{x^2 data}, {exp data}}`. This has then to be transposed to yield a list of pairs of numbers, which can then be plotted:

```
ListPlot[{data[[All, 2]], data[[All, 4]]} // Transpose]
```

**A simpler solution** however uses the rich syntax of the [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Part.html) function. You usually don't see [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Part.html) written explicitly, as it is abbreviated using `[[ foo ]]`. Here's how this version works:

```
ListPlot[data[[All, {2, 4}]]]
```

The output of both of these is exactly the same:

> [image]

A value table for this can be displayed in a similar way, using `Grid`:

```
data = Table[{x, x^2, Sin[x], Exp[x]}, {x, 0., 10}];
Grid[data[[All, {2, 4}]], Dividers->{All, None}]
```

> [image]

Answer (score 9):

It hasn't been mentioned yet, so: the Statistical Plots package features the function `PairwiseScatterPlot[]`, which allows you to compare your data by columns all at once. (If you only need to do two, the other solutions have already given the recipe.)

Here's a sample:

```
<< StatisticalPlots`

data = Table[{x, x^2, ArcTan[x], Exp[x]} + RandomReal[]/100, {x, 0, 10}];

PairwiseScatterPlot[data, DataLabels ->
                    Map[TraditionalForm, {x, x^2, ArcTan[x], Exp[x]}]]
```

[image: pairwise scatter plot example]

Comment: or just `Map[ListPlot, 
 Outer[Transpose[{#2, #1}] &, data\[Transpose], data\[Transpose], 
  1], {2}]`