# Plotting columns of two separate data lists

Tags: plotting

I have two data lists with names data1 and data2. data1 has 8 columns and data2 has two columns. How can I plot 3rd column of data1 verses 1st column of data2?

Comment: You may be interested in [elegant operations on rows and columns](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3069/5478)

Comment: Possible duplicates: [(962)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/962/121), [(14884)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14884/121), [(18236)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18236/121)

Answer (score 3):

one way.

```
data1 = RandomReal[1, {10, 8}];
data2 = RandomReal[1, {10, 2}];
x = data2[[All, 1]];
y = data1[[All, 3]];
(data = Transpose[{x, y}]) // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]], 
  Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {{"y(x)", None}, {"x", "my nice plot"}}, 
   GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]